# Setting a select option from .css('font-family')

Tags: jquery

I have a font drop-down select element:

```
<select id="font">
                <option selected value="Font"></option> 
                <option selected=”selected” value="Arial">Arial</option>
                <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
                <option value="Century">Century</option>
                <option value="'Comic Sans MS'">Comic</option>
                <option value="'Courier New, Courier, mono'">Courier New</option>
                <option value="'Geneva, sans-serif'">Geneva</option>
 </select>
```

I'd like to read the css font-family for an element, cellContent$ below,  and have that option in the select be selected:

```
var fontFamily = cellContent$.css('font-family');
$('#font').val(fontFamily);
```

The code above doesn't work because fontFamily comes back as "Courier New, Courier, mono" and the val parameter has to be exactly what is in the option. The code below, for example, works:

```
$('#font').val("'Courier New, Courier, mono'");
```

So how can I get the thing returned by css('font-family') into exactly what is in the option, i.e., double-quote + single-quote + string + single-quote + double-quote?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var fontFamily = "'" + cellContent$.css('font-family') + "'";
$('#font').val(fontFamily);
```

**EDIT:**

You need an approach like this:

```
var optionArray = $("#font>option").map(function() { return $(this).val(); });

var fontFamily = cellContent$.css('font-family');

for(var i=0;i<optionArray.length; i++){
    if(optionArray[i].indexOf(fontFamily)>0){
        $('#font').val(optionArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eSwj2/1/

Comment: This wouldn't work because some of the values of the `SELECT` list are not encapsulated with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would strip all single quotes from the values of the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to concatenate the quotes:

```
var fontFamily = "'" + cellContent$.css('font-family') + "'";
fontFamily = fontFamily.replace(/''/g, "'");
$('#font').val(fontFamily);
```

**Update**: After learning that you have indeterminate quotes, you may first strip all options off their quotes and then apply value:

```
$('#font').children("option").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("value", $(this).attr("value").replace(/'/g, ""));
});


var fontFamily = cellContent$.css('font-family');
fontFamily = fontFamily.replace(/'/g, "");
$('#font').val(fontFamily);
```

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/YJ2Ns/**

Comment: Same as below, this wouldn't work as some values of the `SELECT` list are not encapsulated with single quotes.

Comment: You've gone the wrong way with your replace, if you look at the values of the `SELECT` list some contain quotes and some don't. If `cellContent$.css('font-family')` returned `Calibri` and you added quotes to it, it wouldn't match any values in the list.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Would you be in position to strip all options off their quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I tried stripping out the single quotes from the option values in the HTML but I still didn't get a match with the value returned by  .css('font-family').  This turned out to be because the option string had extra spaces between the alternative fonts.  But even when I took these out of the option values, I didn't always get a match: the .css('font-value') string looked identical to the option value when I placed them on top of each other, but no match. To always get a match I had to copy the string returned by .css('font-family') and paste it into the HTML option value.

Thanks for all the suggestions.